# cannot create a mongocxx::instance object if one has already been created

Tags: c++, mongodb

I made an class to invoke and test mongo-cxx-driver and I create an `mongocxx::instance` in my constructor.

```
MongoDBHelper::MongoDBHelper()
{
    mongocxx::instance inst{};
}
```

The problem is when I init the second instance of my class object, it turns out:

```
cannot create a mongocxx::instance object if one has already been created
```

it would be a little strange if I put  `mongocxx::instance` in the global scope or use `std::call_once`. How can I fix it?

Comment: Why not make it a class static variable if global feels strange? It seems like it wants to be treated as a singleton instance.

Answer (score 4):

from : http://mongocxx.org/api/current/classmongocxx_1_1instance.html

> Class representing an instance of the MongoDB driver.
>
> The constructor and destructor initialize and shut down the driver, respectively. Therefore, an instance must be created before using the driver and must remain alive until all other mongocxx objects are destroyed. After the instance destructor runs, the driver may not be used.
>
> Exactly one instance must be created in a given program. Not constructing an instance or constructing more than one instance in a program are errors, even if the multiple instances have non-overlapping lifetimes.

It seems you can't have 2 instances, but maybe you can create/destroy one then recreate/destroy an other.

Where your first instance come from?

Comment: "even if the multiple instances have non-overlapping lifetimes" means it won't let you recreate it

Comment: Well, so static/singleton/global is forced by design

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. Libraries that mongocxx depends on in turn enforce singleton initialization semantics, so there is little we can do. I would have much preferred to design a stateless library, but I was forced to compromise.

Comment: At one point, you actually *could* destroy and re-create the instance, but that feature was removed by a subsequent maintainer because apparently the underlying C driver can't handle that: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/commit/84894600054b978408422b4203bdd0e6a8df20f3